# Too big Array or ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I've asked myself quite some times, wether a way too big Array
`int[] test = new int[1000]` 
or an ArrayList `ArrayList<int> test = new ArrayList<int>()`would be better in terms of performance. Which one should I use?

Comment: What programming language is this? Java has no `ArrayList<int>` because of its terrible generics, and .NET has no generic `ArrayList`—only non-generic `ArrayList` and generic `List`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right, it should be Integer.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always better to use a container that automatically adapts to the size of its contents, rather than a fixed-size container that you *assume* will always be big enough.  A hard-coded size like `new int[1000]` is a red flag that means the program has an arbitrary limit of 1000 values and will probably fail in a bad way if it ends up needing more than that.

Answer (score 1):

`int[]` will be much better than `ArrayList<Integer>` from the memory point of view because `Integer` object will require more memory than `int` primitive. However the speed of access of elements is very difficult to comment, because it depends on the JVM.

The add method in `ArrayList` will perform slower than the index based assignment. The bottom line is that, if you can tell exactly the size of array before declaration than use `int[]` else use `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Its not difficult to comment on at all-  the array will be faster in all cases.  Access is a simple pointer addition.  The arraylist version will have a function call, including virtual function lookup then (most likely) the same array access.

Comment: Actually arrays are internally implemented as objects in Java, therefore I think the access speed will depend on JVM. The `array.get(i)` might be doing the same thing as `array[i]`

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the question more clear. I just wanted to know wether it would be better to use an Array, that is way too big, or an ArrayList if I dont (exactly) know how big it needs to be. The ArrayList<Integer> was just an example, It could have also been ArrayList<MyTestObject>/MyTestObject[].

Comment: @TimoV : Since the `Object[]` and `ArrayList<Object>` will require almost same amount of memory, the memory overhead for `ArrayList` will be negligible (especially for a large `ArrayList`). As far as execution speed is concerned, operations like `remove()`, `insert()` will be slow in case of `ArrayList`. And since you do not know the size of array it will be much more better to go for `ArrayList`.